# Fitting svgs in divs with multiple elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I am new to using svgs in CSS.  My goal is to place the svg that I have referenced below (a battery icon) inside of the divs of `item` class, centered vertically, in the first case to the left of the bullet (in the item labeled `foo`), and in the second case to the right of the text (in the item labeled `bar`).

I have tried using changing the display of the image to `inline-block`, and inserting

`<image xlink:href="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/62382/low-battery.svg" />`

within the item (see below), but this does not work.  What is the best practice with inserting svg elements inline in divs with other elements?  Should `span` or `background-size:contain` be used?

```css
#foo { background: #00FF7F; }
#bar { background: #ff0000;}


.items { text-align: center; font-weight: 500; color: #fff; border-width: 2px;
border-color: #fff; padding: 2px;}


.item, .item-selected{ display: inline-block; font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border-width: 2px;
 background-color: #484848;
 opacity: 0.85;
 border-color: green;
 border-width: 2px;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 2px;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}

.item-selected{
background-color: #fff;
color: #181818;

}

.bullet { display: inline-block; margin: 3px 3px 0px 10px;  width: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 7px; }
.label { display: inline-block; font-weight: 300;}


image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='items'>
  <div class='item' id= 'wrk'><image xlink:href="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/62382/low-battery.svg" /><div class='bullet' id='foo'></div><div class='label'>foo</div></div>
  <div class='item-selected' id = 'brk'><div class='bullet' id='bar'></div><div class='label'>bar</div></div>
</div>

<svg>       
<image xlink:href="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/62382/low-battery.svg" />    
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use svg as image using `img` then adjust CSS for alignment:

```css
#foo {
  background: #00FF7F;
}

#bar {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.items {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #fff;
  padding: 2px;
}
img {
 vertical-align:middle;
}

.item,
.item-selected {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: #484848;
  opacity: 0.85;
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-selected {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #181818;
}

.bullet {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 3px 0px 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 300;
}

image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='items'>
  <div class='item' id='wrk'>
    <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/62382/low-battery.svg" height="20" width="40" >
    <div class='bullet' id='foo'></div>
    <div class='label'>foo</div>
  </div>
  <div class='item-selected' id='brk'>
    <div class='bullet' id='bar'></div>
    <div class='label'>bar</div>
    <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/62382/low-battery.svg" height="20" width="40" >
  </div>
</div>
```